# Serialize a dictionary containing pandas data-frames (Python)

Tags: python, serialization, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict containing several pandas Dataframe (identified by keys) , any suggestion to effectively serialize (and cleanly load) it . Here is the structure (a pprint display output ).  Each of dict['method_x_']['meas_x_'] is a pandas Dataframe. The goal is to save the dataframes for a further plotting with some specific plotting options.

> {'method1':
>
> > {'meas1':
> >
> > > ```
> > >                           config1   config2
> > >                    0      0.193647  0.204673
> > >                    1      0.251833  0.284560
> > >                    2      0.227573  0.220327,
> > > ```
> >
> > ```
> > 'meas2':
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >                           config1   config2
> > >                    0      0.172787  0.147287
> > >                    1      0.061560  0.094000
> > >                    2      0.045133  0.034760,
> > > ```

'method2':

> > {  'meas1':
> >
> > > ```
> > >                           congif1   config2
> > >                    0      0.193647  0.204673
> > >                    1      0.251833  0.284560
> > >                    2      0.227573  0.220327,
> > > ```
> >
> > 'meas2':
> >
> > > ```
> > >                           config1   config2
> > >                    0      0.172787  0.147287
> > >                    1      0.061560  0.094000
> > >                    2      0.045133  0.034760}}
> > > ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [pickle.dump(s) and pickle.load(s)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). It actually works. Pandas DataFrames also have their own method df.save("filename") that you can use to serialize a single DataFrame...

Answer (score 2):

In my particular use case, I tried to do a simple `pickle.dump(all_df, open("all_df.p","wb"))`

And while it loaded properly with> `all_df = pickle.load(open("all_df.p","rb"))`

When I restarted my Jupiter enviroment I would get a `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xef'.`

One of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas) state that we can use [HDF5 (pytables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907460/serialize-a-dictionary-containing-pandas-data-frames-python) to do the job. From their docs:

> HDFStore is a dict-like object which reads and writes pandas

But it seems to be picky about the `tables`version that you use. I got mine to work after a [`pip install --upgrade tables`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59477090) and doing a runtime restart.

If you need a overall idea on how to use it:

```
#consider all_df as a list of dataframes
with pd.HDFStore('df_store.h5') as df_store:
    for i in all_df.keys():
        df_store[i] = all_df[i]
```

You should have a `df_store.h5` file that you can convert back using the reverse process:

```
new_all_df = dict()
with pd.HDFStore('df_store.h5') as df_store:
    for i in df_store.keys():
        new_all_df[i] = df_store[i]
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  The h5py.org documentation is a nightmare but perhaps that's simply because hdf5 is a nightmare.