# pd.read_hdf throws 'cannot set WRITABLE flag to True of this array' and 'No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I run

```
pd.read_hdf('xxx')
```

I got

> `cannot set WRITABLE flag to True of this array`

. I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210073/pd-read-df-throws-cannot-set-writable-flag-to-true-of-this-array) which suggest to downgrade numpy from 1.16.0 to 1.15.x

However, after downgrading numpy to 1.15.4, a new error comes

> `No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`

. For this error, someone [suggests](https://github.com/alpacahq/pylivetrader/issues/73) to upgrade numpy to 1.16.0 .

Anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: The first error is due to an intentional behavior change in numpy, which previously allowed unsafe behavior. `pd.read_hdf` will need to be updated to handle this. The second is due to a broken installation that consists of multiple conflicting numpy versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jupyter notebook or Google Colaboratory use `!pip install numpy==1.15.0` before import numpy module and restart kernal or runtime. I had the same problem and solved it in this way.