# Inconsistent pandas read_csv dtype inference on mostly-integer string column in huge TSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types, type-inference

I have a tab separated file with a column that should be interpreted as a string, but many of the entries are integers.  With small files read_csv correctly interprets the column as a string after seeing some non integer values, but with larger files, this doesnt work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1']*100000 + ['X']*100000 + ['1']*100000, 'b':['b']*300000})
df.to_csv('test', sep='\t', index=False, na_rep='NA')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test', sep='\t')
print df2['a'].unique()
for a in df2['a'][262140:262150]:
    print repr(a)
```

output:

```
['1' 'X' 1]
'1'
'1'
'1'
'1'
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Interestingly 262144 is a power of 2 so I think inference and conversion is happening in chunks but is skipping some chunks.

I am fairly certain this is a bug, but would like a work around that perhaps uses quoting, though adding 
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
for reading and writing does not fix the problem.  Ideally I could work around this by quoting my string data and somehow force pandas to not do any inference on quoted data.

Using pandas 0.12.0

Comment: The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) make it look like this would work: `pd.read_csv('test', sep='\t', converters={'a':str})`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski and it totally does! You should add this as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've tricked the read_csv parser here (and to be fair, I don't think it can *always* be expected to output correctly no matter what you throw at it)... but yes, it could be [a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4691)!

As @Steven points out you can use the converters argument of [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('test', sep='\t', converters={'a': str})
```

A lazy solution is just to patch this up after you've read in the file:

```
In [11]: df2['a'] = df2['a'].astype('str')

# now they are equal
In [12]: pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, df2)
```

Note: If you are looking for **a solution to store DataFrames**, e.g. between sessions, both pickle and HDF5Store are excellent solutions which won't be affected by these type of parsing bugs (and will be considerably faster). *See: [How to store data frame using PANDAS, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-data-frame-using-pandas-python/17098736#17098736)*

Comment: this is my fallback but involves extra lines of code every time I read a file which I was trying to avoid

Comment: solution is probably not to use to_csv/read_csv to store you DataFrames, to_pickle or hdf5_store are much better solutions (and neither will be affected by this kind of parsing bug).

Comment: the longer term solution is to migrate to HDF5Store as you say

Answer (score 6):

To avoid having Pandas infer your data type, provide a `converters` argument to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

> `converters` : dict. optional
>
> Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels

For your file this would look like:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('test', sep='\t', converters={'a':str})
```

My reading of the docs is that you do not need to specify converters for every column.  Pandas should continue to infer the datatype of unspecified columns.