# How to convert non-numeric entries to NaN in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan, converters

I am reading in a file with:

```
pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype={'ID_1':float})
```

The file looks like:

```
ID_0, ID_1,ID_2
a,002,c
b,004,d
c,   ,e       
n,003,g
```

Unfortunately `read_csv` fails complaining it can't convert '  ' to a float.

What is the right way to read in a csv and convert anything that can't be converted to a float into NaN?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html Take a look at the `converters` argument you can pass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get pandas.read\_csv to read empty values as empty string instead of nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867028/get-pandas-read-csv-to-read-empty-values-as-empty-string-instead-of-nan)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify the `dtype` param and pass `skipinitialspace=True` then it will just work:

```
In [4]:
t="""ID_0,ID_1,ID_2
a,002,c
b,004,d
c,   ,e
n,003,g"""

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), skipinitialspace=True)
Out[4]:
  ID_0  ID_1 ID_2
0    a   2.0    c
1    b   4.0    d
2    c   NaN    e
3    n   3.0    g
```

So in your case:

```
pd.read_csv("file.csv", skipinitialspace=True)
```

will just work

You can see that the `dtypes` are as expected:

```
In [5]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), skipinitialspace=True).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
ID_0    4 non-null object
ID_1    3 non-null float64
ID_2    4 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

Comment: I think  it is skipinitialspace not skipinitialwhitespace which you have at the start of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is my understanding of reading the documentation:

```
def my_func(x):
    try:
        converted_value = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        converted_value = 'NaN'
    return converted_value

pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype={'ID_1':float}, converters={'ID_1':my_func})
```

(As I am at work now and don't have access to `pandas` I cannot tell you if it works but it looks as it should (said every programmer ever..))

See also these relevant SO questions:

- [Inconsistent pandas read_csv dtype inference on mostly-integer string column in huge TSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471859/pandas-read-csv-dtype-inference-issue)
- [Convert percent string to float in pandas read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669588/convert-percent-string-to-float-in-pandas-read-csv)
- ...and the [`pandas.read_csv` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)