# Remove double quotes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I have the following file:

```
"j"; "x"; y
"0"; "1"; 5
"1"; "2"; 6
"2"; "3"; 7
"3"; "4"; 8
"4"; "5"; 3
"5"; "5"; 4
```

Which I read by:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter='; ', engine='python')
```

Then I print `print df` and see:

```
   "j"  "x"  y
0  "0"  "1"  5
1  "1"  "2"  6
2  "2"  "3"  7
3  "3"  "4"  8
4  "4"  "5"  3
5  "5"  "5"  4
```

Instead, I would like to see:

```
   j  x  y
0  0  1  5
1  1  2  6
2  2  3  7
3  3  4  8
4  4  5  3
5  5  5  4
```

How to remove the double quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it with:

```
rm_quote = lambda x: x.replace('"', '')

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter='; ', engine='python', 
     converters={'\"j\"': rm_quote, 
                 '\"x\"': rm_quote})

df = df.rename(columns=rm_quote)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the type as an argument to the `read_csv` function.

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter='; ', engine='python', dtype=np.float32)
```

You can read more in [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)

Also, you can use [to_numeric](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) function.

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: `convert_objects` is deprecated

Comment: @TedPetrou , Thanks, I've updated it to use the `to_numeric` method

Comment: Why would you use `apply` here instead of just using the function itself. `pd.to_numeric(df, errors='ignore')`. Also, to_numeric is a function not a method.

Comment: I got `ValueError: The 'dtype' option is not supported with the 'python' engine`. and `ValueError: ('Unable to parse string', u'occurred at index "j"')`, for the alterntive aproach.

Comment: @KcFnMi , You are right.. in this case you can use the converters argument. You can get help in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471859/pandas-read-csv-dtype-inference-issue)  and in [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways one might do that, such as using: [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html).

Considering that one wants to update the column of the following DataFrame

[image: Example of DataFrame]

And let's say that you want to remove the double quotes from the first column.

With [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) one can do

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace(r"[\"]", '')
```

Or

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('"', "")
```

This last one will also remove quotation marks if they appear along the element. If for example one has `"236"76"`, it will turn into `23676`.

With [`str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), to remove quotes from the ends of the strings, one can do

```
df[0] = df[0].str.strip('"')
```

Here is the final result

[image: Output after running the code above]

Comment: What if I have `"` in between the text i.e. in Column 1 lets say I have "236"76"

Comment: No this wont. Instead, I found this `df[0] = df[0].str.strip().str[1:-1]` useful.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more generic solution that was useful in my case:

```py
def remove_quotes(datum: object) -> object | str:
    if type(datum) is str:
        return datum.replace('"', '')
    else:
        return datum

# Define the column names.
names = ['j', 'x', 'y']

df = pd.read_csv(
    'test.csv',
    delimiter=';\s',
    engine='python',
    header=0,  # Ignore header.
    names=names, # Rename the columns at reading time.
    converters={name: remove_quotes for name in names},
)
```