# Pandas msgpack vs pickle

Tags: python, pandas, msgpack

`msgpack` in Pandas is supposed to be a replacement for `pickle`.

Per the [Pandas docs on msgpack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#msgpack-experimental):

> This is a lightweight portable binary format, similar to binary JSON,
>   that is highly space efficient, and provides good performance both on
>   the writing (serialization), and reading (deserialization).

I find, however, that its performance does not appear to stack up against pickle.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 100))

>>> %timeit df.to_pickle('test.p')
10 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop

>>> %timeit df.to_msgpack('test.msg')
10 loops, best of 3: 36.4 ms per loop

>>> %timeit pd.read_pickle('test.p')
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop

>>> %timeit pd.read_msgpack('test.msg')
10 loops, best of 3: 24.6 ms per loop
```

**Question:**  Asides from potential security issues with pickle, what are the benefits of msgpack over pickle?  Is pickle still the preferred method of serializing data, or do better alternatives currently exist?

Comment: checkout this pretty comprehensive study: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization/. *msgpack* is quite awesome when  you have a non-trivial amount of data.

Comment: that blog page no longer exists

Comment: @JasonS Try: https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization. Oddly, it is just a trailing `/` in the top link.

Comment: I wrote msgpickle.  It's a fast, safe pickler that's easily extendible.  Combines msgpack with a simple object pickler

Comment: @ErikAronesty Thanks for mentioning it.  For others, here is the [link](https://pypi.org/project/msgpickle/) on PyPI.  It requires Python >= 3.11

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Pickle is better for the following:

1. Numerical data or anything that uses the buffer protocol (numpy arrays) (though only if you use a somewhat recent `protocol=`)
2. Python specific objects like classes, functions, etc.. (although here you should look at `cloudpickle`)

#### MsgPack is better for the following:

1. Cross language interoperation.  It's an alternative to JSON with some improvements
2. Performance on text data and Python objects.  It's a decent factor faster than Pickle at this under any setting.

As @Jeff noted above [this blogpost](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization) may be of interest

Comment: am I right to say that 4D panels are not supported for pickle too?

Comment: @firefly: in pandas 0.18 Panel4D is pickleable.  But consider xarray instead of Panel4D.

Comment: to_msgpack() crashes for bigger size data, I am not sure about to_pickle()

Comment: what do you mean by "crashes for bigger size data" - can you expand on that?

Comment: As of 2019, MsgPack support for Pandas has been deprecated, and the recommendation is to [use pyarrow instead](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27722).

Comment: i made my own "msgpickle" lib that can handle objects