# Writing huge Pandas HD5 dataframe to disk

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big multiindex Pandas dataframe made by objects in each column (about 81900 rows × 24 columns) and I need to save it as an hdf but when I do:

```
df.to_hdf(path2filename,mode='a',key='main')
```

it fails telling me:

```
OverflowError: value too large to convert to int
```

What is the best way to save such a huge dataframe. I'd like the hdf because this dataframe is part of a group of dataframe that I would like to keep grouped together, but if there are no solutions I can explore other possibilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OverflowError while saving large Pandas df to hdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078803/overflowerror-while-saving-large-pandas-df-to-hdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, I already saw that post but it didn't help me