# KeyError reading json_pickle(d) tweets into dataframe using read_pickle

Tags: python, json, pandas, twitter, jsonpickle

Using python 2.7 and the jsonpickle and pandas library I saved a number of tweets to a .txt file using `jsonfile.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweets._json,unpicklable=False)+'\n')` 
which encodes the json value of the tweet using the `jsonpickle` package

when i try to read the txt file into a pandas dataframe in a different script using 
`tester = pandas.read_pickle(fileToProcess)`

My traceback's most recent call is

> File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
>       dispatchkey
>   KeyError: '{'

I get the same error with a number of files I created. 
Here is an example file 3.8MB in size [Sample Tweets File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B36Iq5nWyHEFRVE4OE84SFFwQ1U/view?usp=sharing)
I'm new to json files but can an panda or a pickle expert help me get my tweets into a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read_pickle` method is intended to deserialize data *created* with the pickle module, e.g. data serialized with `to_picke` method of `Series`, `DataFrames` or `Panel`. Like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17098736/5509239).

If you are using `jsonpickle.encode`, you should be using the dual method provided by the library, `jsonpickle.decode` to deserialize your data.

In general, I think you are better of using pandas' serialization mechanism.

But if you want too badly to use `jsonpickle`:

1. Note the following from documentation,

   > If you will never need to load (regenerate the Python class from JSON), you can pass in the keyword unpicklable=False

So, you shoudn't passk `unpicklable=False` to the `encode` methdod.

2. You appear to be saving each object to a line in your file, so you should do.

Something along this lines,

```
tweets = []
for line in fileToProcess:
    line = line[:-1]  # Drop '\n' char
    tweets.append(jsonpickle.decode(line))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and guidance. If I wanted to end up with a pandas dataframe would you recommend a different data structure to use instead of the array after decoding (should the last line of the loop read tweets.append(jsonpickle.decode(line)) ?

Comment: I've fixed the variable name in the `jsonpicke.decode` part. If you have your data as json and want to convert it to a `DataFrame`, doesn't [`pandas.read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_json.html) do what you want? You could save the data as a file and later process it with pandas.