# Save Pandas df containing long list as csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to save a pandas dataframe as .csv file. Currently my code looks like this:

```
with open('File.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

The saving works but the problem is that the lists in my dataframe are just compressed to [first,second,...,last] and all the entries in the middle are discarded. If I just look at the original dataframe all entries are there. Is there any way how I can convert the list to a string which contains all the elements (str(df) also discards the middle elements) or how I can save a full numpy array in a cell of a csv table?

Thank you for your help,
Viviane

Comment: I don't see any reason you the code you have doesn't work. I did notice that you are appending to the file rather than creating a new file. Are you sure the file didn't already have the data as you describe and if you look at the end of that file it has the entire dataframe?

Comment: Yes, for my purpose I need to append and no, it is not already at the end, sorry

Comment: No, `df.to_csv('File.csv', header=False, mode='a')` should write __all__ values into the file. Could you produce a __reproducible__ code?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','A'])
hot = np.zeros(9999)
ID = 1
df=df.append({'ID': int(ID),'A':hot}, ignore_index=True)
with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably convert elements present in the list using join method.

example:

```
lst =  ['Hello!','I','am', 'Pandas User','.']
strng = ' '.join(lst)
print (strng)
```

hope this helps to you.

Comment: Thank you, that works :) It would have been nice if there is a way how pandas just saves everything in the csv file without that trick but this is a good way to work around it.

Comment: I'm glad this work around works for you. I'd love to understand why your original code wasn't working. Hopefully someone who knows will still post an explanation!

Answer (score 6):

I had issues while saving dataframes too. I had a dataframe in which some columns consisted of lists as its elements. When I saved the datfarme using `df.to_csv` and then read it from disk using `df.read_csv`, the list and arrays were turned into a string of characters. Hence `[1,2,3]` was transformed to `'[1,2,3]'`. When I used HDF5 format the problem was solved.

If you dataframe is called `df_temp`, then you can use:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
store['df'] = df_temp
```

to save the dataframe in HDF5 format and you can read it using the following command:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
df_temp_read = store['df']
```

You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas). I should also mention that pickle did not work for me, since I lost the column names when reading from the file. Maybe I did something wrong, but apart from that, pickle can cause compatibility issues if you plan to read the file in different python versions.

Comment: This should probably be the selected answer. Works with dataframes containing multiple lists of multiple data types

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work properly. I couldn't reproduce described behavior.

Here is a bit more "pandaic" version:

```
df.to_csv('File.csv', header=False, mode='a')
```

PS pay attention at the `mode='a'` (append) parameter...

**UPDATE:**

[How to get rid of ellipsis when **displaying / printing** a DF:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_columns", 0):
    print(df)
```

Comment: I agree that this _should_ also work, but I see no reason why the original code didn't work. They should be equivalent. `DataFrame.to_csv` accepts either a filename or a file buffer.

Comment: @RyanSandridge, that's correct - thank you! I've updated ny answer accordingly...

Comment: It still doesn't work for me for some reason, I've posted some sample code as a comment on the top. The join string workaround works however

Comment: @Viviane, how do you check the written CSV?

Comment: I checked it by looking at the file in excel and with this code:
`test = pd.read_csv('test.csv',names=['ID','A']).set_index('ID')
type(test['A'][1])` (output: str , no way to recover the data which was replaced by '...')

Comment: @Viviane, check it in a Text or HEX editor - for example in `Notepad++`

Comment: I can't see more in any editor that I tried... And after all, I need to get the information into python somehow

Comment: I don't know if I am overlooking something but I use this code: 
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','A'])
hot = np.zeros(9999)
ID = 1
df=df.append({'ID': int(ID),'A':hot}, ignore_index=True)
with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=False,mode='a')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv',names=['ID','A']).set_index('ID')
with pd.option_context("display.max_columns", 0):
    print(test['A'])`

And the output is:
ID
1    [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]

Comment: @Viviane, try it this way: `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':hot}).assign(ID=1)` instead of your code...

Comment: It seems clear that the problem was not with the file, but how @Viviane examines the file.

Comment: @RyanSandridge, the [way he is creating DF in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857982/save-pandas-df-containing-long-list-as-csv-file/47858808?noredirect=1#comment82683283_47858808) causes problems when saving it to CSV...

Comment: Yes I agree with Max, I haven't found any way in which I can open it and see everything of the list. However when creating the df like Max proposed It saves everything. I am not sure if I can use this way of creating the Df in my case though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `pd.to_hdf()` and the `pd.read_hdf()` functions in pandas could simply realize the saving and loading hdf5 files' requirements without installing the tables package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).