# Storing & Adding Pandas DataFrame In A Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop that generates random results every time thanks to my Generate_Dataframe function.  So the name columns stay the same but my "Result" column is always a different float value.

```
def Generate_Dataframe():
 #Do Some Stuff
  return DataFrame
```

an example of what I get back would be something like...

```
DataFrame
Name 1       Name 2        Result
Joe          Smith           5.5
Jake         Smith           4.5
Jim          Smith           2.5
Joanne       Smith           1.5
```

So when I run my loop I'm generating dataframes like the one above, I want to be able to update/add the Result column each time.

```
for x in range(1,5):
    New_DataFrame = Generate_DataFrame()
```

I haven't been able to find a way to store the dataframe.  Optimizing for speed would be great.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you are using the `name` columns like indices.  You should put them there and then update/add becomes trivial.

```
def gen_df():
    midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        ('Joe', 'Smith'),
        ('Jake', 'Smith'),
        ('Jim', 'Smith'),
        ('Joanne', 'Smith')
    ], names=['Name 1', 'Name 2'])
    return pd.DataFrame(
        dict(Result=np.random.rand(4)),
        midx
    )
```

---

**Option 1**
You don't have to do it this way.  But this is how I'd do it:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(pd.DataFrame.add, (gen_df() for _ in range(1, 5)))

                 Result
Name 1 Name 2          
Joe    Smith   2.400550
Jake   Smith   2.222812
Jim    Smith   2.601639
Joanne Smith   0.503774
```

---

**Option 2**
In a loop

```
df = gen_df()

for _ in range(1, 5):
    df += gen_df()

df

                 Result
Name 1 Name 2          
Joe    Smith   1.998055
Jake   Smith   2.268697
Jim    Smith   2.815204
Joanne Smith   2.253301
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the dataframe I think the best way is to save to a pickle/csv files. 
df.to_pickle(file_name)/df.to_csv(file_name)

You can read: [How to store a dataframe using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas)