# How to store a pandas dataframe in the smallest format possible?

Tags: python, pandas, save, disk

There is a lot of documentation on the most efficient way to store pandas dataframes (e.g. [How to store a dataframe using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas)), but most of the resources focus on i/o time efficiency.

I would like to save large pandas dataframes, which typically use several Gb of disk storage in a `csv` format, to a more lightweight format without losing any information.

The [LightGBM Dataset](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html) looks promising, but I did not manage to correctly reload my data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I usually use `joblib` which saves in binary. I hear `df.to_feather` is also efficient, but never try.

Comment: I use pandas to_hdf with blosс compression. Look at the comparison here:
https://dziganto.github.io/out-of-core%20computation/HDF5-Or-How-I-Learned-To-Love-Data-Compression-And-Partial-Input-Output/

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d "As our little test shows, it seems that feather format is an ideal candidate to store the data between Jupyter sessions. It shows high I/O speed, doesn’t take too much memory on the disk and doesn’t need any unpacking when loaded back into RAM."

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for filesize, Apache Parquet may be your best friend.
As @wkzhu's article suggests, this achieves the best compression, particularly if you have categorical data.