# Is there a way to save my processed Dataframes in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tokenize

I'm new to Jupyter Notebooks and I was wondering if there is a way to save my (Preprocessed Data) instead of re running the file each time. I'm working on a NLP project where steps like (Lemmatization and Tokenization) takes a huge amount of time. so I don't want to re run the file each time I open it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned Dataframe in the topic, you should check: [How to store a dataframe using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas)

If there is some different requirement, please specify.