# save panda DataFrame efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a data frame from lot of excel files that took about 2 hours by looping to import it in pandas. now I have to work on it in some different times is there any way that I could save it and then load it again efficiently.

Comment: what is the size of your dataframe ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas) solves your problem ?

Comment: you can save it as parquet file.

Comment: i have 200 million rows and 100 columns in my DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

you can save your pandas data frame  and load it any time you want to work on it using. For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
               index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
               columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: I have 200million rows in my DataFrame.

Comment: that doesnt matter you can still use this code to save your data frame

Comment: bibi excel men 1m rows hoti han only.

Comment: sorry my bad you can try saving it in chunks

Comment: If you’re working with massive excel files, try not to. They’re very difficult data structures to process — especially when your data is large. Consider serialized formats such as parquet, csv, json, or pickle (python’s binary stream).

Comment: so instead of using df.to_excel use df.to_csv. Hope it helps