# Is there a function to save loaded datasets into a text / or any file?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Good day,
Is there any way to save my loaded datasets (contain 80500 data) and convert them to a file? (ex. txt, h5 file) so I don't need to load them for the second time.

[image: the data successfully loaded after 5 hours.]

tried to save the data using these code but it is not working, any solution?

```
 final = {"train_data":train_data,"test_data":test_data,"valid_data":valid_data,"train_label":train_label,"test_label":test_label,"valid_label":valid_label}
    
    import joblib
    
    joblib.dump('data_label_train_test_valid_grayscale_haar.txt')
```

Comment: Best way is to save them as json. Alternatively you can use pickle for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store a dataframe using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas)