# Saving a DataFrame as .csv, with columns data type: object (list). Load the DataFrame but the columns data type are object (str), what am I missing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I saved a DataFrame as a .csv file, some of the DataFrame columns are populated with python list objects, but when I reload the same DataFrame, the columns that were populated with python list objects are now populated with python string objects.
See code outputs.

```
   type(df['col1'][0])
   out>> list
   print(df['col1'][0])
   out>> ['a', 'b', 'c']

   df.to_csv('df.csv')
   df_reloaded = pd.read_csv('df.csv')


   type(df_reloaded['col1'][0])
   out>> str
   print(df_reloaded['col1'][0])
   out>> "['a', 'b', 'c']"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Found the answer to my question here: [How to store a dataframe using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-store-a-dataframe-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

The csv file format cannot store arrays, it can only store text.

Comment: I loaded DataFrame where pandas objects where recognized as dictionaries by python. I think that I am  missing an argument when using pandas.to_cvs method to save the DataFrame!?

Comment: In your original code, a single data element in the dataframe was a list. Could you try splitting those lists into seperate columns? I think the problem is you're trying to store too much data in a single pandas cell. Hope that helps!