# Is there any way to save the output from your code as a data frame so it can be re-used ? Running a series of t tests and want to collate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a series of very simple t tests- using researchpy. Output is as follows (for one of the 10 t test I've ran):

```
                      Independent t-test      results
 0  Difference (No Breakdown - Breakdown) =        1.5992
 1                     Degrees of freedom =   118229.0000
 2                                      t =        0.8508
 3                  Two side test p value =        0.3949
 4                 Difference < 0 p value =        0.8026
 5                 Difference > 0 p value =        0.1974
 6                              Cohen's d =        0.0934
 7                              Hedge's g =        0.0934
 8                          Glass's delta =        0.0934
 9                            Pearson's r =        0.0025)
```

Ideally, I want to collate all the values and rank them by feature. Is there any way to save this output as a dataframe? Apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17098736/7758804 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570065/7758804