# Dictionairy issue with string key

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I am currently working on a project where I'm implementing an Image Captioning problem using a CNN network. The issue is that whenever I try to pass an image name as a key to a dictionary, with the image features as a value, it's passing an Index error.

```
def load_features(photos):
    all_features = load(open('features.p', 'rb'))
    features={k:all_features[k] for k in photos}
    return features
```

Here, features.p is a pickle file containing the features of all the images, and photos is meant to be a loaded text file with all of the image names. The image names are a combination of alphebetical and numeric values with the .jpg extension. How could I solve the issue?

Comment: What is the type of `all_features`? You're assuming it's a dict, but `IndexError` implies it's a list. A dict would give `KeyError`. What's a little odd is that `IndexError` also suggests that `k` is an `int`. (If `all_features` was a list and `k` was a string, then you'd get a `TypeError`.)

Comment: In fact, perhaps `all_features` is a numpy array?

Comment: `all_features` is supposed to be a pickle file, not a numpy array

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(type(all_features))` after the `load` statement? (Many types of object can be pickled, so knowing that the object was created by loading a pickle file doesn't tell us what its type is.)

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right. I suppose I just didn't check. It does appear that `all_features` is a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? @slothrop

Comment: Does the array actually have any strings in it that you can relate to the image names, or is it purely numeric?

Comment: The array is supposed to hold a bunch of image features, so I suppose you could call it a numeric array, yes

Comment: OK, so the data you pickle does not contain any strings? If so, I'd say you should go back and revise the code that does the pickling, so that the data (in whatever structure) includes the image names. Without that, you can't really relate the data after unpickling back to the names.

Comment: Specifically, you could consider using a pandas DataFrame, where the index values are the image names, and you have a column per feature. There are various ways to save and load that object: pickling is one, and there are other options too, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098654/how-to-reversibly-store-and-load-a-pandas-dataframe-to-from-disk

Answer (score 1):

The `IndexError` you're encountering could be due to mismatched keys in the `photos` list and the keys in the `all_features` dictionary loaded from the `features.p` file. To debug this issue, you can add some print statements to understand which key is causing the problem. Here's an example of how you can modify your `load_features` function to include some debugging information:

```py
def load_features(photos):
    all_features = load(open('features.p', 'rb'))
    features = {}
    for k in photos:
        try:
            features[k] = all_features[k]
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Key '{k}' not found in the 'all_features' dictionary.")
    return features
```

When you run this modified function, it will print out the keys that are causing the `KeyError`. This information should help you identify any discrepancies between the keys in `photos` and the keys in `all_features`.

Comment: Just tried it, it's still throwing the IndexError from before. Seems like the issue is with using the image titles as keys at all. Any fixes?

Comment: If using the image titles as keys is causing issues, you can try a different approach. Since the image titles are unique identifiers, you can use them to create a mapping between the image titles and their corresponding features without directly using them as dictionary keys.

Comment: That would mean using two lists, no? One for the unique identifiers of each image and one for the features themselves. A bit clunky, maybe. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As you say in the first sentence, OP is encountering an `IndexError`. So `except KeyError` isn't going to catch that.