# Most memory efficient reader/writer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I want to call `pandas.read..`function, what is the most memory efficient reader/writer, which would save the most memory on my machine? I want to read a large datafile and wonder if I can pick a format upfront to save the data with some other tool to save some memory consumption in python.

Is it: `pd.read_csv, pd.read_hdf, ..`?

The fast file is explained here: [Fastest file format for read/write operations with Pandas and/or Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941147/fastest-file-format-for-read-write-operations-with-pandas-and-or-numpy)

is this also the most memory efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use modin library. It is meant to speed up most of the data frame operations. You can find more information here at this link https://github.com/modin-project/modin.

Comment: interessting package, but does not answer my package completly