# Reading large data in memory in python

Tags: python, scipy

I have data as follows:

```
2000\t120000
2000\t123
1920\t23943
32\t48832
```

The first column corresponds to userid and second column corresponds to item id
Note, these ids doesnt start from 0.

So, I am trying to run this dataset against
https://github.com/gamboviol/bpr/blob/master/bpr.py

```
 data = mmread(sys.argv[1]).tocsr()
```

This dataset is around 5gb.. Whats an efficient way to convert my data into this format?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables)? An HDF5 store (using [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) under the hood) can read in huge arrays of numeric data very quickly. See [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628329/hdf5-and-sqlite-concurrency-compression-i-o-performance) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas).