# Why does sqlite3 not work on Amazon Elastic File System?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, sqlite, nfs

When I try to create a base with `sqlite3` on a EFS directory, this results in an error:

`$ sqlite3 foo.db
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .log stderr
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo (int bar);
Error: disk I/O error`

The Sqlite3 database in question is supposed to story meta data only and will be updated infrequently. Concurrent access is not required. However, it is required that if the process creating the Database dies, the process can be restarted on a different host and carry on where the previous instance quit.

Amazon claims that [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/faq/) is a "file system that [is] accessible to Amazon EC2 instances via a file system interface (using standard operating system file I/O APIs) and that support full file system access semantics (such as strong consistency and file locking)." Thus, I'm assuming it is fit for the task at hand.

The mount options in `/etc/fstab` are:

> eu-west-1a.fs-ID.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:/ /efs nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 0 0

I understand that [it is often generally discouraged to put databases on NFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907429/locking-sqlite-file-on-nfs-filesystem-possible). However, I believe, given the language used by both Amazon and SQLite, developers will keep trying.

Comment: Use `.log stderr` to get more error information.

Comment: @CL. `.log stderr` produces no addtional output

Comment: Before you try to write anything.

Comment: @CL. I understand, see my edit above. This is what I get.

Comment: Update your `sqlite3` tool.

Comment: `strace` the process to see what system calls are involved.  I've observed that EFS appears to use very large (> 32 bit) inode numbers, fwiw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update (March 6, 2017):**

EFS now supports NFS v4.1 lock upgrades and downgrades:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/amazon-elastic-file-system-amazon-efs-now-supports-nfsv4-lock-upgrading-and-downgrading/

<s>From the docs:</s>

> Lock upgrades and downgrades: Amazon EFS returns  NFS4ERR_LOCK_NOTSUPP
>   if the client attempts to upgrade or downgrade an existing lock.
>
> **Note**
>
> Because lock upgrades and downgrades are not supported, use cases that
>   require this feature, such as those using SQLite or IPython, are also
>   not supported in Amazon EFS.

See:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-ug.pdf

and also:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/nfs4-unsupported-features.html

Comment: EFS now supports Lock upgrades and downgrades. See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/amazon-elastic-file-system-amazon-efs-now-supports-nfsv4-lock-upgrading-and-downgrading/

Comment: Thanks @user1071840, I am glad to hear this for my use case as well. I will update my answer as not to lead people astray that find it.

Comment: I'm still encountering this issue on my AWS setup, anything special you defined in you EFS/Grafana setup to make it work?

Comment: Sounds like a question for AWS support.

Answer (score 5):

By default sqlite runs on "unix" [VFS](https://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) which uses unsupported by Amazon EFS lock upgrades. But you can use sqlite databases on Amazon EFS if you change VFS to "unix-excl", which uses exclusive file locks and doesn't require upgrades.

There are several ways to specify VFS. If you are using command line, just add "-vfs unix-excl" option:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1 /efs> sqlcipher foo.db -vfs unix-excl
SQLCipher version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo (int bar);
sqlite> .exit
```

If using from API, then you need to register VFS before calling open function:

```
sqlite3_vfs_register(sqlite3_vfs_find("unix-excl"), 1);
sqlite3_open("foo.db", &db);
```

If using PHP PDO, then you're stuck, unless you are willing to recompile pdo_sqlite PHP extension.

Comment: Good to know, it is possible after all to run sqlite on EFS.

Comment: Possible, but still a bad idea generally: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html